# Prevent usb tethered device from claiming default route?

Tags: android, tethering

I'm tethering an android device over USB.  When tether is accomplished,  the device sets the usb0 interface as the default route.

I do not want this (usually,  the host device has wlan0) but do not see a simple way to change in Ubuntu.  dhcpcd does not have the --nohook option and --nogateway also doesn't seem to work in this case.

'route del' and 'route add' can obviously be used,  but are quite..... a hardcoded solution,  since they require the actual IPs etc.

Any ideas?  TIA.

No solution so far-- could obviously be scripted.

Answer (score 1):

Open Networking > Wired Connections > Click on Android USB Tether > IPv4 > Routes > Tick "use only for resources on this network".

This will make it skip adding the default route to this connection, making whatever other connection the default one.

Answer (score 0):

I guess a simple solution wwould be to not activate tethering on your Android when its not needed. I'm not sure if that is what you are asking, or if you want a more technical way of doing this via Ubuntu.

Comment: In which case,   I wouldn't have IP connectivity to the device :P